# How to test to observe Latency Differences when running Cassandra on HDD vs SSD

Tags: cassandra, stress-testing, datastax-enterprise

We had a 3 node cluster running on HDDs. After migrating to SSDs, we ran a load test but haven't seen any latency difference.

So we are thinking about running a stress test. Is there any threshold or parameters we should set or any general recommendation to find the utmost difference?

Comment: define latency, do you mean if write or in read path ? What is the cluster configuration (with replicas ?) What tests do you conduct and what are the results you observer before and after.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should run a diagnostics test on the cluster itself instead. There might be some unknown entity(ies) that would be preventing the latency difference. Even on a load test, you should see a significant difference.